# Cordova Network Detection Plugin not responding

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Here I import the plugin, it all works well here.

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information

npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

Adding it to the app.module.ts, and declaring it as a provider...

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Network
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Injecting in the constructor, now I think here is the problem when I am using the this.network.onConnect();

```
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private toast: ToastController, private network: Network, public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}

ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  }, error => console.error(error));

  this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

I am playing with wifi turning it on/off but no log in console..
And I know I am doing everything right but still ?

Answer (score 0):

`ionViewDidEnter` should be inside of the `HomePage` class.

```
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(private toast: ToastController, private network: Network, public navCtrl: NavController) {}


    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        }, error => console.error(error));

        this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy code from answer and paste to user home.ts file

Comment: Updated​ answer, saying syntax error is not correct in this case. Let me know if it works.

Comment: What I did is create a new project and still nothing :(

Comment: `ionViewDidEnter() {console.log(this.network)}`, check what you get.